# Python Win32 hide subtotals of pivot table

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I've got the following code:

def pivot_table(wb: object, ws1: object, pt_ws: object, ws_name: str, pt_name: str, pt_rows: list, pt_filters: list, pt_fields: list):
"""
wb = workbook1 reference
ws1 = worksheet1 that contain the data
pt_ws = pivot table worksheet number
ws_name = pivot table worksheet name
pt_name = name given to pivot table
pt_rows, pt_cols, pt_filters, pt_fields: values selected for filling the pivot tables
"""

```
# pivot table location
pt_loc = len(pt_filters) + 2

# grab the pivot table source data
#to edit with new data
pc = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=ws1.Range("A9:Q10807"))

# create the pivot table object
pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=f'{ws_name}!R{pt_loc}C1', TableName=pt_name)

# selecte the pivot table work sheet and location to create the pivot table
pt_ws.Select()
pt_ws.Cells(pt_loc, 1).Select()
# Visiblity True or False
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).ShowValuesRow = False
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).RowGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).ColumnGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).RowAxisLayout(win32c.xlTabularRow)
```

Now I would like to hide subtotals for all columns with python. Anyone know how to do this?

I've tried the following:

```
#pt_ws.PivotTables("User ID").RowGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables("User ID").ColumnGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables("User Group").RowGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables("User Group").ColumnGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables("Risk Description").RowGrand = False
pt_ws.PivotTables("Risk Description").ColumnGrand = False
```

Hpwever this gives an error..

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'PivotTables method of Worksheet class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the Subtotals [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.subtotals) at the end of the Remarks part, you need to set all values of Subtotals tuple to be False.

To hide all subtotals your code should look like that

```
for field in fields:
    field.Subtotals = tuple(False for _ in range(12))
```

here `field` should be an item from the PivotFields collection. For example, to disable subtotals for `User Id`

```
pt.PivotFields('User Id').Subtotals = tuple(False for _ in range(12))
```